# How to generate random numbers and add prefix based on given N in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a following pandas dataframe:

```
Prefix  Count
98510   3
98472   2
98435   4
98011   1
98452   2
```

Now based on prefix and Count I have to generate unique random numbers for each prefix between 00000 to 99999 and add them to prefix
The output should look like this

```
Numbers
9851015651
9851058616
9851069815
9847279462
9847263458
9843556984
9843591329
9843513584
9843532564
9801112358
9845265841
9845279154
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Simply posting a problem statement is a homework dump, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @HenryYik That doesn't do what the OP requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `repeat` and `np.random.randint`:

```
np.random.seed(1)  # for repeatability - remove the command or change seed if you want

df.Prefix.repeat(df.Count)*100000 + np.random.randint(0, 100000, df.Count.sum())
```

Output:

```
0    9851098539
0    9851077708
0    9851005192
1    9847298047
1    9847250057
2    9843573349
2    9843521440
2    9843598448
2    9843520609
3    9801149100
4    9845207751
4    9845243757
Name: Prefix, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you for solution. I still have one problem though. can I group by "prefix" column and create random number among them, so that each prefix will have chance to get random number from 0 to 99999. the solutions you have given creates random number total of "Quota" column and add prefix to them. by doing that not all prefix gets chance to get random number from 0 to 99999. thanks in advance

Comment: You really don't need to do so. Theoretically, product of uniform distributions is still a uniform distribution. Practically, you'd get the same result with a lot more code.

Comment: lets suppose np.random.randint(0, 100000, df.Count.sum()) gave 56291.. and that random number got added to the first prefix 98510. .now for other prefix 56291 wont be available. I want to make number 0 to 99999 available for every prefix. but should be unique among the prefix. can you help me to do that

Comment: No, `np.random.randint` doesn't care about duplicates. You may still have two `56291`.

Comment: yes I realized that. I tried <<np.random.choice(range(99999), size=df.Quota.sum(), replace=False)>> for unique, but I cant groupby for each prefix to make number (0,99999) available for every prefix like I want.

Comment: by using np.random.randint I got duplicates within prefix